# How to make a movieclip appear and reappear in the same location?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation, flash-cs5

Well, I'm working on a shooting game in which I have to click enemies to make two counters count the number of hits I get. In this case the enemies are ghosts and I tried making some kind of animation when they are shot so the animation replaces them after I click on them.

However I can't seem to make them reappear again in the same location, it's a very simple drawing made with the shape and drawing tools of Flash CS5.

The code I use in this case for the shooting part is this one:

```
function disparar (event:MouseEvent):void{
    contar +=1;
    disparos.text = contar.toString();

    var destino1:Boolean = this.mira.hitTestObject(this.FRojo)

    if (destino1 == true){
        cuenta +=1;
        aciertos.text = cuenta.toString();
        this.FRojo.visible = false;
        colorante.color = 0xFF0000;
        this.bang.transform.colorTransform = colorante;
        this.bang.x = this.FRojo.x;
        this.bang.y = this.FRojo.y;
        this.bang.scaleX = this.FRojo.scaleX;
        this.bang.scaleY = this.FRojo.scaleY;
        this.bang.play();
        this.FRojo.visible = true;
    }
```

In fact you can see the whole file in [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/joubbxz3f4sdtkc/ejercicio%202.fla), it's very simple, but I can't seem to make the movieclip either disappear and reappear or make the animation that follows reappear each time I hit one of the ghosts. Could anyone help me with this? I'd really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're hiding the movie clip by setting `this.FRojo.visible = false;` and then setting it back to true pretty much right after so it never hides.

Try replacing `this.FRojo.visible = true;`

with

`setTimeout(function(){FRojo.visible = true;}, 1000);`

That will make it reappear after 1 second (1000 milliseconds).

So remove `this` and make sure each one is FRojo, FAzul and FMorado.

If you use a tweening library like greensock you can do some cool fades rather than it just reappearing.

**EDIT**

You have another error inside your `BANG` movie clip. On frame 10 replace

```
this.bang.x = 50;
this.bang.y = 10;
this.bang.scaleX = 1;
this.bang.scaleY = 1;
```

with

```
this.x = 50;
this.y = 10;
this.scaleX = 1;
this.scaleY = 1;
```

Comment: You're a lovely person, you. Thank you very much!! It works perfectly now, thank you a lot <3